# What species are the skulls seen in Dr. McCoy's office from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Dr. McCoy, aka Bones, has a couple of weird skulls in his office, as seen in the following picture from the episode "[Is There in Truth No Beauty?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Is_There_in_Truth_No_Beauty%3F_(episode))" (they are highlighted with red arrows and the frame is from around the ~47:21 mark):

[image]

They definitely look non-human and are probably not from any other Federation species we have seen in the series, so my question is: **which species are the skulls from?**

In-universe answers are preferable, but out-of-universe trivia about the props might be considered as well.

Comment: The white one looks a lot like an orangutan skull

Comment: It also looks like a troll skull from Skyrim ( https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Troll_Skull_(Skyrim) ) but that's another franchise :D

Comment: The Mighty Warrior McCoy bathes in the blood of his enemies and makes pen-holders from their bones!

Comment: https://forgottentrek.com/forgotten-aliens-of-the-motion-picture/  the black one is possibly Zaranite - they have that dual lobe skull in-universe though obviously the new aliens of TMP have little to no connection to TOS out universe.  So I don't think a factual answer is possible.

Comment: The white skull looks felid.  I suspect they were going for Caitian.